# Run two commands synchronously in a split terminal

Tags: batch-file, conemu

I would like to launch my development server using a single launch script in a split console with ConEmu. It can be a ConEmu task, a batch script, or whatever it takes. I have achieved this with Gulp but find that solution to be overkill.

I need to execute

```
cd C:\Repo\myApp\frontEnd
npm start
```

I would then like to split the window `cmd -new_console:s50H`

And without waiting for `npm start` to finish, because it does not, execute the following in the new window. Syncronously so to speak.

```
cd C:\Repo\myApp\backEnd -new_console:s50H
node backEnd.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really care about executing `npm start` **before** creating new split with backend?

If you don't - the simplest way is starting backend before frontend. Actually, due to some minor delays in processing, your `npm start` may start same time or even before than `node`.

```
cd /d C:\Repo\myApp\frontEnd
node backEnd.js -new_console:s50H -new_console:d:"C:\Repo\myApp\backEnd"
npm start
```

Another option is starting `npm` in background and `node` thereafter.

```
cd /d C:\Repo\myApp\frontEnd
ConEmuC -async -c npm start 
node backEnd.js -new_console:s50H -new_console:d:"C:\Repo\myApp\backEnd"
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried to determine this from the docs but they proved to be a bit challenging. Thank you for being available here. :)